# Spectrum of symmetric Toeplitz matrix

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix is Toeplitz if it is constant on the diagonals parallel to the main diagonal.
I am looking for references on the spectrum of finite symmetric Toeplitz matrices over finite fields.